# LinkedIn Follow button Google Chrome Content Security Policy script-src report-sample

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Trying to put a LinkedIn Follow button onto the site, it works fine in Firefox, but does not in Chrome with this error in Console:

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src'
>   contains an invalid source: ''report-sample''. It will be ignored.

Same problem on LinkedIn own Follow button generation page: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

Same message in Console and nothing happens when button is clicked.

This happens only in Chrome currently (from browsers i've checked). Must be related to https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/

#linkedin #chrome

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same thing. There appears to be a CSP issue with their implementation. The response to the GET request that is initiated when  you click the button has its X-Frame-Options header set to to sameorigin so the browser isn't evaluating the response.

I reported the issue with examples to LinkedIn and they said they would have an engineer take a look.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's definitely problem at their side, and i've also contacted them first, but was told that the better way to contact support is to create a topic at SO with a #linkedin tag, although don't see any official reply in couple days. Thanks again